# Windows PHP-CLI truncates included scripts

Tags: php, windows, php-5.6

I'm really baffled by an issue of running a small PHP application on Windows using the CLI (5.6).

I am simply running my app with:

`bin\php -f sync.php`

**What I get is a syntax error issued out of an `include`'d file**. The bizarre thing is, it appears that PHP is actually truncating my included script during processing. I know this because if I remove some of that scripts content (reducing total bytes), I can eventually get it to process without error.

Other relevant information:

- Running PHP 5.6
- Running on a Windows 7 VM
- Application function is to connect to a SQLLocalDb instance
- PHP sqlsrv driver is installed
- Errors are thrown when included script exceeds ~633 bytes
- I have tried to switch both encoding and line endings to remedy without success

If you think the error output is relevant, here you go:

```
PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input:  ' in S:\config.php on line 27

Warning: Unexpected character in input:  ' in S:\config.php on line 27
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in S:\config.php on line
27

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in S:\config.php on line 27
```

If I eliminate some characters from that script while keeping valid syntax, it will execute without error. Any thoughts as to the cause?

---

**Edit**: It turns out that something may be wrong with the format of my included script. So I'm posting it for context. Maybe it's been that long since I've worked on Windows, that I am forgetting some bizarre rule about PHP syntax:

```
<?php

/**
 * Configuration settings.
 * 
 * PHP Version 5
 * 
 * @category  Configuration
 * @author    XXXXXX XXXXXXXX
 * @copyright 2016 XXXXXX XXXXXXXX, XXX. All Rights Reserved.
 */

$config = array(
    'magento' => array(
        'wsdl'      => 'http://redacted-url-still-filling-needed-size/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1',
        'username'  => 'user',
        'password'  => 'pass',
    ),
    'last_sync' => '2016-09-01 00:00:00',
    'db' => array(
        'adapter'   => 'app_db_sqlsrv',
        'host'      => 'localdbt',
        'name'      => 'dbname',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => 'password',
    ),
);
```